# Google Ads API for Python: '_Rendezvous' object has no attribute 'request_id'

Tags: python, google-api, google-ads-api

I have been trying to replicate the following code sample for Google Ads API using the Python client library. Let me preface by saying, I completed the authentication process and configured the `google-ads.yaml` file with the `developer_token`, `client_id`, `client_secret`, `refresh_token`, and `login_customer_id`. The sample code that I am looking to replicate is below, you can also view this at the following [GitHub repository](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/blob/master/examples/v0/basic_operations/get_campaigns.py).

```
# Copyright 2018 Google LLC
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
"""This example illustrates how to get all campaigns.
To add campaigns, run add_campaigns.py.
"""

from __future__ import absolute_import

import argparse
import six
import sys

import google.ads.google_ads.client


_DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = 1000


def main(client, customer_id, page_size):
    ga_service = client.get_service('GoogleAdsService')

    query = ('SELECT campaign.id, campaign.name FROM campaign '
             'ORDER BY campaign.id')

    results = ga_service.search(customer_id, query=query,page_size=page_size)

    try:
        for row in results:
            print('Campaign with ID %d and name "%s" was found.'
                  % (row.campaign.id.value, row.campaign.name.value))
    except google.ads.google_ads.errors.GoogleAdsException as ex:
        print('Request with ID "%s" failed with status "%s" and includes the '
              'following errors:' % (ex.request_id, ex.error.code().name))
        for error in ex.failure.errors:
            print('\tError with message "%s".' % error.message)
            if error.location:
                for field_path_element in error.location.field_path_elements:
                    print('\t\tOn field: %s' % field_path_element.field_name)
        sys.exit(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # GoogleAdsClient will read the google-ads.yaml configuration file in the
    # home directory if none is specified.
    google_ads_client = (google.ads.google_ads.client.GoogleAdsClient
                         .load_from_storage('google-ads.yaml'))

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Lists all campaigns for specified customer.')
    # The following argument(s) should be provided to run the example.
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--customer_id', type=six.text_type,
                        required=True, help='The Google Ads customer ID.')
    args = parser.parse_args()

main(google_ads_client, args.customer_id, _DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE)
```

I tried running the above code in a couple of different ways in the command prompt as follows:

```
> python get_campaigns.py --customer_id 'xxx-xxx-xxxx'
> python get_campaign.py --customer_id 'xxxxxxxxxx'
```

I even commented out the lines after declaring the google_ads_client variable  and just supplied the customer id manually

```
main(google_ads_client, 'xxxxxxxxxx', _DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE)
main(google_ads_client, 'xxx-xxx-xxxx', _DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE)
```

and ran the script that way. For all these instances, I was still getting the same error

```
AttributeError: '_Rendezvous' object has no attribute 'request_id'
```

Any help, would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
python get_campaigns.py --customer_id "123456789"
```

without quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to define or request the page size. You're not supplying a token, which you need but don't supply.

Considering your query is only to request the campaigns, [I'd suggest you use this version without the paging](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/blob/506cba4608acb6cee9efa8a6f06070a7eb51953d/examples/basic_operations/get_campaigns.py) or token need (paging is not required in the new Google Ads API unless you want to actually implement paging yourself which I don't believe you do).

That version will give you the exact same results as the first one, without the paging.